# Automatic log out warning using RxJS + Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

Trying to implement idle timer and automatic logout in a single observable. I'm still new to RxJS and trying to get a handle of nesting observables. I have the below code that should be self-explanatory, but I'm trying to do:

- Open a warning (modal) when user is idle for `timeoutLogoutWarning` milliseconds
- The warning itself as two buttons: one that navigates user to the Logout page, which then it will forget the logged in user, and another button that simply closes the warning
- When warning is opened, set another idle timer for `timeoutLogout` until actually logging out. Using an idle timer instead of a regular timer to prevent the user suddenly logging out as they are about to press a button on the warning modal.

I am just starting to learn about `switchMap` and thought its use is a good idea to cancel the timer when the user starts interacting with the screen, but I also need the inner observable (which opens the modal) to not be cancelled when the warning modal is open so I have a boolean that 'blocks' the outer observable when the modal is open.

I'm not sure if my approach is correct, but right now the outer timer does not restart after the user dismisses the warning modal. What am I doing wrong?

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let logoutWarningIsOpen = false;

    const interaction$ = merge(
      timer(0),
      fromEvent(window, 'mousemove'),
      fromEvent(window, 'keydown'),
      fromEvent(window, 'touchstart')
    );

    this.logoutSubscription = interaction$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => {

        return timer(0).pipe(

          // don't fire when logout warning modal is open
          takeWhile(() => !logoutWarningIsOpen),

          // time until logout modal will be open
          delay(this.timeoutLogoutWarning),

          switchMap(() => {
            logoutWarningIsOpen = true;
            const modal = this.modal.open(this.modalTemplate);

            return merge(

              // setting logoutWarningIsOpen to false should cancel inner observable
              merge(modal.closed, modal.dismissed).pipe(
                tap(() => logoutWarningIsOpen = false),
                delay(10)
              ),

              // logout timer that resets when user interaction detected
              interaction$.pipe(
                switchMap(() => timer(this.timeoutLogout))
              )
            )
          })
        )
      })
    ).subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/Logout']));
  }
```

Comment: See if [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-dialog-example-edupala-s7xrxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - took a couple of hours of researching operators but I was able to implement a correctly working solution and encapsulate it in a service called `IdleLogout`.

The main idea is to use `mergeMap` to open the modal to warn about logout and maintaining a counter `modalIsOpen` to determine whether modal can be opened or not. The observable created from `mergeMap` either emits true or false depending on whether logout should be initiated.

```
// time in minutes until modal is opened
const idleTime = 10;

// time in minutes, after warning modal is opened, until user is automatically logged out
const logoutTime = 5;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class IdleLogout {
  constructor(private modal: NgbModal, private router: Router) { }

  private stopped$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  private modalRef: NgbModalRef | null = null;

  private modalIsOpen = 0;

  // time in milliseconds until modal is opened
  private idleMilliseconds = idleTime * 60000;

  // time in milliseconds, after modal is opened, until user is automatically logged out
  private logoutMilliseconds = logoutTime * 60000;

  private interaction$ = merge(
    timer(0),
    fromEvent(window, 'mousemove'),
    fromEvent(window, 'keydown'),
    fromEvent(window, 'touchstart')
  );

  // timer that resets on user interaction (before modal is opened)
  private idle$ = this.interaction$.pipe(switchMap(() => timer(this.idleMilliseconds)));

  // timer that resets on user interaction (after modal is opened)
  private delayLogout$ = this.interaction$.pipe(switchMap(() => timer(this.logoutMilliseconds)));

  // observable opens modal and emits when modal is closed or dismissed
  private modal$ = timer(0).pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      this.modalRef = this.modal.open(LogoutWarningModal);
      this.modalRef.componentInstance.minutes = logoutTime;
      this.modalIsOpen++;
      return merge(this.modalRef.closed, this.modalRef.dismissed).pipe(
        tap(() => this.modalIsOpen--)
      );
    })
  )

  /**
   * Enables auto logout on a component
   */
  watch() {
    this.idle$.pipe(
      filter(() => !this.modalIsOpen),
      mergeMap(() => race(
        this.delayLogout$.pipe(map(() => true)),
        this.modal$.pipe(map(() => false))
      )),
      filter(result => result),
      take(1),
      takeUntil(this.stopped$)
    )
    .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/Logout']))
  }

  /**
   * Call on ngOnDestroy() to prevent behavior from carrying over after component destroyed
   */
  stop() {
    this.stopped$.next(true);
    this.stopped$.complete();
  }
}
```

Service is used on a component by calling `watch()` on component initialization and `stop()` on component destroy:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.idle.watch();
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.idle.stop();
}
```